# c++ tron 2d array repeating

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get a trail to appear behind the player bike but for some reason instead of a "x" appearing behind the player every time it moves, the player would actually duplicate itself. It sounds a little confusing but you should compile this code yourself and see what i mean. What I am trying to do is just have a trail of "x" behind the player instead of the player leaving a trail of "P". thanks

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "windows.h"
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    //prototype functions used
    void DisplayMap();
    void PlayerBike();
    void setCursorTo();
    void SetBike();
    //global variables that will be used by different functions
     int PlayerX = 10;
     int PlayerY = 70;
     bool GameOver = false;
     const int H = 25; // const variable so it doesnt change size
     const int W = 82;// const variable so it doesnt change size
     char Map[H][W]; // char map with HxW
     char trail = 'x'; // this is where the trail is initialized as a * 
    int main()
    {

         SetBike();
         DisplayMap();
    while (GameOver == false){
        setCursorTo();

        PlayerBike();



    } // end while loop

        return 0;
    }//end main



    void DisplayMap(){ // display map function

    for(int i = 0; i < H; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j < W; j++){

            if(i == 0 || i == 24 || j == 0 || j == 81 ){ Map[i][j] = 'x';} // characters in row 24x81 are changed to x
            cout << Map[i][j]; // output map
        } // end for loop
            cout << "\n"; // create new line to output the map correctly

    } //end for loop


    } // end DisplayMap function


    void SetBike(){

    Map[PlayerX] [PlayerY] = 'P';

}
    void PlayerBike(){
        Map[PlayerY][PlayerX]= trail; // I would like this trail to repeat behind the player but it does not appear at all. 
        if (kbhit()) {// get user key input
        char GetCh = getch(); // GetCh equal to the button the user presses
        if (GetCh == 'w'){PlayerX = PlayerX - 1; Trailx = Trailx -1;}
        else if (GetCh == 's'){PlayerX = PlayerX +1; Trailx = Trailx +1;}
        else if (GetCh == 'd'){PlayerY = PlayerY +1;}
        else if (GetCh == 'a'){PlayerY = PlayerY - 1;}
    }// end kbhit
    }// end PlayerBike function

    void setCursorTo() // stops constant flashing on the map
    {
        HANDLE handle;
        COORD position;
        handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        position.X = 0;
        position.Y = 0;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, position);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DisplayMap` function is flawed.

First, it seems you are not only *displaying* the map, you are also actively *modifying* it. Put the drawing-a-border into a separate `initMap` function, which also zeros out all other positions with a space (it seems you didn't do that yet, so perhaps that is where it goes wrong). You only need to call `initMap` once.

Next, do not draw the player `P` in the `DisplayMap` function. Draw this *once*, before entering the game loop. Then: if the user pressed a valid move key,

1. put an `x` on the player's position
2. update player position
3. put a `P` on the new position
4. redraw the screen by calling `DisplayMap`
5. and you'll see the trail stays put.

Possible refinements: *before* accepting a 'move' command by updating the position, check if the map contains a space or something else. If it contains a space, you can execute the move; if not, play an explosion animation (`*oO*+.`). Also, consider looking up the `switch` statement in your favourite C reference, to avoid endless long sequences of `if..else`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I set the map, the player bike "SetBike()" outside of the loop so now they do not repeatedly draw over and over in the loop. Once I set the player and map outside, I do not have the ability to move the player character anymore with the PlayerBike() function and how exactly do i keep updating the map? doesnt the setCursorTo(); function do that already?

Comment: Your `setCursorTo` definitely does *not* do that. See your own code ... It appears to me you implemented my suggestions only partially -- especially the points 1 to 5. I see you moved `DisplayMap` out of the loop; sorry, this should be *in* -- I meant taking the `P` out. Care to try again?

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you through email or skype? I need more help with this :(

Comment: Sorry, that's not what Stackoverflow is for. It's not elance.com.

Comment: Nono i am not looking to hire you for anything.. This is a school assignment and I shouldn't post this online for other students to find and copy my work that's why.. :/

Comment: I managed to get the trail to show up finally, its just my map keeps lagging really badly, not sure whats going on but I don't want to post my entire code for a possibility of another student taking parts of it. If i can send it to you privately and get some tips, that would help me out a lot. thank you